# Linux can't get data through a pipe

Tags: linux, sockets, pipe

I don't know what is wrong with this program, it's been going fairly well so far, but I'm stuck with a problem.
I have a parent with 2 children, one has to verify a command, and one has to verify a username.
It does that, but when it comes to the second child, it seems I can't get through the information I need.
My pipes and socket have to be kept open, so that they communicate at each time I've come up with a result on each side.

Help me find everthing that's wrong with this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
//sys variables

char Input[100], commandLogin[100], Output[100], Username[50], possibleUsername[50];
int readDescriptor, logEval;
int readDescriptor2;
pid_t childPid;


int commandCatcher(int logEval){

//define socket
    int socketOne[2];
    int socketTwo[2];
    int pipeOne[2];

    if(logEval == 0)
        if(socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, socketOne) < 0){
            perror("socket - err"); 
            exit(0);
    }

    if(logEval == 0)
    switch(fork()){//first child
        case -1:
            perror("fork - err");
            exit(1);

        case 0:
            childPid=getpid();
            readDescriptor = read(socketOne[0], commandLogin, sizeof(commandLogin));

            if (strcmp(commandLogin, "login") == 0 ){

                printf("Log eval from first:%d\n", logEval);
                write(socketOne[0], "ok", strlen("ok") + 1);
                //something to do here so that the child knows it was given the username

                exit(1);
            }

            else {
                printf("Try again.\n");
                write(socketOne[0], "none", strlen("none")+1);
                exit(1);
            }

    }

        if(pipe(pipeOne) == -1){
            perror("pipe - err");
            exit(0);
        }

    if(logEval == 1){

        switch(fork()){//verify username
            case -1:
                perror("fork - err");
                exit(2);

            case 0:
                readDescriptor = read(pipeOne[0], possibleUsername, sizeof(possibleUsername));
                printf("Username from second child:%s  ---\n", possibleUsername);
                printf("logEval is : %d\n", logEval);
        }
                exit(2);
    }




    //parent

    //getting initial value
    scanf("%s", Input);
 //writing initial value
    write(socketOne[1], Input, strlen(Input)+1);

    readDescriptor = read(socketOne[1], Output, sizeof(Output));
    //printf("output    %s\n", Output);



//verify if the command was correctly given
    if(strcmp(Output, "ok") == 0) {
        printf("Command was accepted. Insert your username: %d\n", logEval);

        scanf("%s", Username);
        write(pipeOne[1], Username, strlen(Username)+1);

        commandCatcher(1);
        }
    else if(strcmp(Output, "none") == 0) {
        printf("Command was denied. Please try again:\n");

        commandCatcher(0);//recursive call
    }

wait(&childPid);

}

int main(){
    printf("Welcome to Sys v1.0. To start off, please insert your command. \n");
    commandCatcher(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first child you are writing to socketOne[0] and in the second child you are trying to read from pipeOne[0]. there is no data in pipeOne[0] so that is the reason why read is failing in your second thread.

```
*readDescriptor = read(pipeOne[0], possibleUsername, sizeof(possibleUsername));*
```